# Attempt to compare nil <= number

Tags: lua, roblox

Does anyone know what's happening with my script? The script works fine for other teams but it's just when I try to select 3 of them they all have the same issue being "attempt to compare nil <= number" I've used this same script in some other games as well and they all worked fine. It's just for this one 3 teams won't work.
I can't upload a picture so I'll have to write the line of code where the error is found.

```
if TeamRequirements[teamn].MinRank <= plr:GetRankInGroup(TeamRequirements[teamn].Group)then
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know what's happening with my script?

Well obviously you're comparing the nil value `TeamRequrements[teamn].MinRank` with the number value returned by `plr:GetRankInGroup(TeamRequirements[teamn].Group)`.
This is not allowed in Lua and you certaintly don't expect that value to be nil.

Find out why in this case `TeamRequrements[teamn].MinRank` is nil and in the other cases you mentioned it is not. We cannot provide more help here as you don't provide the code where `TeamRequirements[teamn].MinRank` is assigned a value.